# Python Regex - using re.sub to clean up a string

Tags: python, regex

I am having some problems using `regex sub` to remove numbers from strings. Input strings can look like:

```
"The Term' means 125 years commencing on and including 01 October 2015."

"125 years commencing on 25th December 1996"

"the term of 999 years from the 1st January 2011"
```

What I want to do is remove the number and the word `'years'` - I am also parsing the string for dates using `DateFinder`, but `DateFinder` interprets the number as a date - hence why I want to remove the number.

Any thoughts on the `regex` expression to remove the number and the word `'years'`?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: And what have you tried? What's wrong with `re.sub(r'\d+\s+years?', '', string)`?

Comment: @FHTMitchell - that worked perfectly. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
import re

my_list = ["The Term' means 125 years commencing on and including 01 October 2015.",
"125 years commencing on 25th December 1996",
"the term of 999 years from the 1st January 2011",
]

for item in my_list:
    new_item = re.sub("\d+\syears", "", item)
    print(new_item)
```

results:

```
The Term' means  commencing on and including 01 October 2015.
 commencing on 25th December 1996
the term of  from the 1st January 2011
```

Note, you will end up with some extra white space (maybe you want that)?  But you could also add this to 'clean' that up:

```
new_item = re.sub("\s+", " ", new_item)
```

<s>because I love regexes: new_item = re.sub("^\s+|\s+$", "", new_item)</s>

```
new_item = new_item.strip()
```

Comment: Isn't the last line of code the same as saying `new_item.strip()`? And to avoid the need for 'cleaning' you could add a `\s` to the regex before the number of after years...

Comment: Ah yes, a simple `new_item.strip()` would probably be better.  I got carried away with regex fun :)

Comment: That was perfect and solved the problem. Unfortunately, datefinder is a little overactive in interpreting numbers as dates so I need to strip numbers not related to a date.

Answer (score 0):

try this to remove numbers and word `years`:

```
re.sub(r'\s+\d+|\s+years', '', text)
```

if for instance:

```
text="The Term' means 125 years commencing on and including 01 October 2015."
```

then the output will be:

```
"The Term' means commencing on and including October."
```

Comment: This goes someway towards what I want to achieve, but it's also removing the numbers from the date. Is there a way to only remove a number before the word 'years'?

Comment: Aha, then this should be an option: `re.sub(r'\s+\d+\s+years', '', text)`